# Subscription to Redis Stream Blocks Connections for Other Requests With Vert.x

Tags: java, redis, vert.x

I'm implementing an application with Vert.x (and their Redis Client library) that is able to listen to Redis Streams. For that I have `n` instances in my app subscribing to it. [The Vert.x documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-redis-client/java/#_connection_pooling) states:

> A common configuration is to set the maximum size of the pool to the number of available CPU cores

The pool provides connections to be used for requests to Redis. For instance, the pool size could to 6. If more than 6 instances trying to subscribe, the first 6 have no problems, but all the instances trying to subscribe afterwards can't because no connections are left.

Is the "common configuration" are hard limit? Could I also have 10k connections?

Does Vert.x provide a way to separate pools for different purposes (for subscriptions and for other stuff)?

Is there a solution to handle many connections mainly used for stream subscriptions with Vert.x?

Unfortunately, the Vert.x documentation doesn't provide much information.

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x redis client will attempt to work with the least number of connections to redis as this usually gives better performance for both vert.x and redis.

When working with simple command and response, for example, `SET key value` then a pool has benefits as it reuses connections and the whole flow is faster. However, for pub/sub, it is best if you use a dedicated connection (not a pool)

```
Redis.createClient(
  vertx,
  "redis://localhost:6379")
  .connect()
  .onSuccess(conn -> {
    // use the connection to subscribe...
  });
```

If you wish to use a pool for subscriptions (which doesn't give any advantage in terms of performance) you still can, but need to tweak the defaults to allow more connections than usual. You'll do this with `RedisOptions` object:

```
new RedisOptions()
    .setConnectionString("redis://localhost:7006")
    // allow at max 128 connections to redis
    .setMaxPoolSize(128)
    // allow 512 connection requests to queue waiting
    // for a connection to be available.
    .setMaxWaitingHandlers(512))
```

This means that there will be 128 connections readily available and for commands that go over the connections in use, the client will queue them up to 512 until a connection is available, otherwise starts failing commands. Usually, this prevents your server to overload Redis or run out of memory/sockets.

Comment: Increasing the max pool size is the first thing I tried out. Redis can handle thousands of connections but the Vert.x only talks about "common configuration". Could I set the max pool size to 10k or would that cause errors? The documenation says nothing about this.

Comment: The max pool size is only limited by the available number of sockets. Theoretically you cannot go over 64k but you probably will be stopped before by the OS. Vert.x itself is single threaded so the number of sockets will not impact the number of threads so it won't impact your application performance in terms of scheduling.